# sql select where something happen that day

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have columns:

```
code     unique          date                     info      name
a123     adfgh           2014-07-14 14:15:00      test      user1
a124     aklgp           2014-08-12 09:15:00      test      user1
a175     opllp           2014-08-12 11:15:00      test      user2
```

And i would like get all records where unique = $variable but in that day.
Exmpl:
if my unique = 'aklgp' i would like see both

```
a124     aklgp           2014-08-12 09:15:00      test      user1
a175     opllp           2014-08-12 11:15:00      test      user2
```

becouse both records are in same day? Is it posible?

I play with DATEDIFF but that not good for my

Comment: what if unique not found still you need day records?

Comment: unique 100% exist. but if not exist than i dont need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is enough, but the idea might be something like that.

```
cast([date] as date)
```

will take the "date" part of your datetime (hoping this is a datetime type), which will give you... a day.

```
select * 
from yourTable
where cast([date] as date) IN (select cast([date] as date)
                               from yourTable
                               where [unique] = 'aklgp')
```

of course, if you have many `aklgp` on different days, you will get more datas. But unique should be... unique, no ?

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6674/3)

**EDIT**

As mentioned by Bulat, you could also use EXISTS

```
SELECT * from yourTable t1
where exists (select null
              from yourTable t2
              where cast(t1.date as date) = cast(t2.date as date)
              and t2.[unique] = 'aklgp')
```

Comment: Yes. But i need get all records when curent record been made

Comment: @user3747585 see sqlFiddle in updated answer ? That's what you'll get.

Comment: @Bulat of course, this is another way (and probably more efficient), I update the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be this too help you,

```
DECLARE @UNIQUE VARCHAR(20) 
SET @UNIQUE = 'AKLGP'

SELECT  * FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE   CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = (SELECT CAST([DATE] AS DATE) FROM [TABLE] WHERE [UNIQUE] = @UNIQUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know a solution using only SQL. Maybe a solution in PHP could offer some help:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE unique = 'aklgp'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

$year = date_format($row['date'], 'Y');
$month = date_format($row['date'], 'm');
$day = date_format($row['date'], 'd');

$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable 
WHERE  (DATEPART(yy, date) = $year
AND    DATEPART(mm, date) = $month
AND    DATEPART(dd, date) = $day)";
```